# django LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL with dynamic value

Tags: django, authentication, url-routing

I'm trying to redirect a user to a url containing his username (like http://domain/username/), and trying to figure out how to do this. I'm using django.contrib.auth for my user management, so I've tried using LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL in the settings:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/%s/' % request.user.username # <--- fail..
```

but it only seems to accept fixed strings, rather than something that'll be determined after the user is logged in. How can I still accomplish this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A solution, is to redirect to a static route like '/userpage/' and have that redirect to the final dynamic page.

But I think the real solution is to make a new view that does what you really want.

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def my_view(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            HttpResponseRedirect('/%s/'%username) 
        else:
            # Return a 'disabled account' error message
    else:
        # Return an 'invalid login' error message.
```

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#authentication-in-web-requests

for more information about rewriting the view. This is how the docs say to override this kind of thing.

Comment: I prefer the first suggestion of redirecting from the static /userpage/. That way, you can still use the login view from `django.contrib.auth.views`, which might be more robust than a hand rolled view.

Comment: as I'm trying to simplify urls and minimize redirects, your solution seems like the way to go. thanks!

Comment: What a simple and brilliant answer that solves my exact question. I feel ashamed for not thinking of this. enjoy your internet point.

Answer (score 8):

With the class-based `django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView`, you can now simply override `get_success_url`:

**urls.py:**

```
url(r'^login$', MyLoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
url(r'^users/(?P<username>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)$', MyAccountView.as_view(), name='my_account'),
```

**views.py**

```
class MyLoginView(LoginView):

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('my_account', args=[self.request.user.username])
```

Comment: This does it for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the auth view in your own custom view and redirect to wherever you want if authentication succeeded.

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib import auth
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

def login(request):
    template_response = auth.views.login(request)

    if isinstance(template_response, HttpResponseRedirect) and template_response.url == '/accounts/profile/':
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('user', args=(request.user.username,)))


    return template_response
```

Another alternative is to use the query param `next` to indicate where to redirect to after the login.

```
<a href="{% url 'login' %}?next={{ request.path }}">sign in</a>
```

Comment: I like the "next" uri parameter best from all of the above answers +1

Answer (score 1):

I use django-two-factor-auth login view which provides OTP features for login.
Hence I extend from two_factor's LoginView.

**In main urls.py:**

```
from two_factor.urls import urlpatterns as tf_urls
urlpatterns = [
  # make sure login is before default two_factor (tf_urls) urls
  # coz first url has higher preference
  path('account/login/', MyLoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
  path('', include(tf_urls)),
]
```

**In views.py:**

```
from two_factor.views.core import LoginView
from two_factor.utils import default_device


class MyLoginView(LoginView):

    def get_success_url(self):
        if self.is_otp_setup() is True:
            return reverse('homepage:homepage')

        # otp not setup. redirect to OTP setup page
        else:
            return reverse('two_factor:setup')
        
    def is_otp_setup(self):
        if self.request.user and \
                self.request.user.is_authenticated and \
                default_device(self.request.user):
            return True
        else:
            return False
```